# translate regions and cities in osclass

Tags: php, gettext, osclass

Is it possible to translate cities as normal text without duplicating any table on the DB and only add the cities and their translations to .po
here is a loop to list all the cities

```
<select name="sCity" class="selectar"  id="Scity">
<option value=""><?php _e('Select a city...')?></option>
<?php foreach($aCities as $city) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $city['s_name'] ; ?>"><?php echo $city['s_name'] ; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

I tried this but didn't  work

```
sprintf(__('%s'),  $city['s_name']);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to translate those since there's currently no tables for it in the Osclass database.

To make it possible, you'll need to add at least two tables: 
`oc_t_city_description`,
`oc_t_region_description`

The structure of those new tables will be similar to `oc_t_pages_description`.

Something like  `fk_i_pages_id`, `fk_c_locale_code`, `s_title`.

You might wan't to ask Osclass team on the github of the project, by submitting an issue.

-

**About your test :**

```
sprintf(__('%s'),  $city['s_name']);
```

Gettext does not execute PHP to make the translation, you're just asking him to translate '%s' and not 'Paris', 'London' or 'San Francisco'.